# Select (distinct) rows that have unique 2 column combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I want to select all rows of this table, where the first two columns are unique (`[RegisterId]`,`[DeviceSerial]`).  Currently the DISTINCT keywords also matches `RegisterName`, which I want it to ignore.  How can I do this? Note that these two columns form part of a compound key, if that matters.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [RegisterId]
                  ,[DeviceSerial]
                  ,[RegisterName],0 AS Contribution
              FROM [RegisterCountLogs]
              WHERE DeviceSerial = 2160563829
```

Comment: Could it work if you just put the `select disinct` of the 2 columns part into a subquery and select on that in an outer query? (i.e. Is RegisterId primary key, or is (RegisterId,DeviceSerial) combination unique in the table)

Comment: My SQL skills are severely rusty, could you post the query?

Comment: If that combination has multiple `RegisterName` values, which do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a group by

```
SELECT [RegisterId]
    ,[DeviceSerial]
    , Max ([RegisterName]),0 AS Contribution
FROM [RegisterCountLogs]
WHERE DeviceSerial = 2160563829
GROUP BY [RegisterId]
    ,[DeviceSerial]
```

Now if you only want rows that have one combination of RegisterId and DeviceSerial, then you have to add a `HAVING`

```
SELECT [RegisterId]
    ,[DeviceSerial]
    , Max ([RegisterName]),0 AS Contribution
FROM [RegisterCountLogs]
WHERE DeviceSerial = 2160563829
GROUP BY [RegisterId]
    ,[DeviceSerial]
HAVING Count (*) = 1
```

.

**EDIT**

On further reflection, you probably want the name on the latest/newest registration.

```
SELECT [RegisterId]
    , [DeviceSerial]
    , [RegisterName]
    , 0 AS Contribution
FROM [RegisterCountLogs]
Where RegisterId =
(
    SELECT Max ([RegisterId])
    FROM [RegisterCountLogs]
    WHERE DeviceSerial = 2160563829
    GROUP BY [DeviceSerial]
)
```

Comment: I had tried this, and it complained about the RegisterName (being a string) and couldnt figure out how to stop it complaining.. Thanks!

Comment: As per your update... The first query works fine, would I only want the second if I wanted to specify that it had only one match (as opposed to many)

Comment: Can you post the query you tried, and the actual error message you received?

Comment: The query I made originally didnt have MAX on the RegisterName.. is was the missing link!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join to weed out the unwanted records.

(untested code)

```
;WITH [CountLogs] as
(
    SELECT [RegisterId],[DeviceSerial],[RegisterName], 0 AS Contribution
    FROM [RegisterCountLogs]
    WHERE DeviceSerial = 2160563829
)
SELECT  RCL1.*
FROM [CountLogs] RCL1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [RegisterId],[DeviceSerial] FROM [CountLogs]) RCL2 
    ON RCL1.[RegisterId] = RCL2.[RegisterId] and RCL1.[DeviceSerial] = RCL2.[DeviceSerial]
```